# How to remove specifc query string parameter from Laravel redirect()->intended('/')?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

How to remove specific query string parameter form redirect()->intended('/') if exist? 
For example redirect()->intended('/') would redirect to:

```
https://www.exampleDomain.com?specificParameter=true&anotherparameter=123
```

And I would like to get rid of "specificParameter=true" before redirection so it will get redirected to this instead:

```
https://www.exampleDomain.com?anotherparameter=123
```

I'm using Laravel 5.3.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's parse_url function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Then you can grab the components you need specifically and create the correct redirection URL.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there is any command like "without" or something in that nature to remove the query string if exist? Looks like I need to pars and remove the query string manually though.